# Add Scrollbar for Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css

The drop down menu can potentially have many items which extends beyond the bottom of the screen.  I need to add a scroll bar to the drop down menu; but can't seem to find a way to.

As you can see from the below .gif, the bottom of the drop down menu is cut off, requiring the scroll bar to be added.  How?  Any suggestions is appreciated.
[image: Click to show drop down menu]

```css
.usermenudropdown {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  width: 339px;
  top: 50px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right shadow" aria-labelledby="notification24">
  <div class="usermenudropdown">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex" *ngFor="let currentUpload of currentUploads" (click)="fixTask(currentUpload)">
        <div class="mr-2" data-cy="pendingUpload" *ngIf="currentUpload.status === 'pending' && currentUpload.type !== 'replicate'">
          <img src="assets/images/icons8-clock-24.png" alt="fix">
        </div>
        <div class="mr-2 rotating" data-cy="uploadingUpload" *ngIf="currentUpload.status === 'processing' || (currentUpload.type === 'replicate' && currentUpload.status !== 'failed')">
          <img src="assets/images/icons8-refresh-24.png" alt="fix">
        </div>
        <div class="mr-2" data-cy="erroredUpload" *ngIf="currentUpload.status === 'failed'">
          <img src="assets/images/icons8-cancel-24.png" alt="fix">
        </div>
        <span class="text-truncate mr-auto my-auto">{{currentUpload.name}}</span>
        <a data-cy="openUploadLink" class="btn text-primary my-auto p-0" style="cursor:pointer;" *ngIf="currentUpload.status === 'failed' || currentUpload.type === 'replicate'">
              {{'schedule_notification_link_open' | translate}}
            </a>
        <button *ngIf="currentUpload.status === 'failed' || currentUpload.type === 'replicate'" type="button" aria-label="Close" data-cy="removeUpload" class="close ml-2" (click)="removeTask(currentUpload)">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex" *ngIf="!erroredUploads?.length && !currentUploads?.length">
        {{ 'no_notifications' | translate }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting a `max-height` on the dropdown. Could be `max-height: 80vh` or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `max-height` to the drop-down menu along with `overflow:auto` which will trigger the scrollbar. The inserted elements will take up as much height as you allow them to and as soon as they stretch the menu to the limit, scrollbar gets triggered.

If you keep the `overflow-y:scroll`, you will see the scrollbar permanently, but it wont work since there is no place to scroll to. Setting `overflow` to auto will show the scrollbar only when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I set my drop-down menu to 100% height (it had been fit content) and auto for my overflow since we have a lot of users who set more than 100% zoom on their browser.

```
  .overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: auto;
```